# problemas para modificar archivo config.inc.php MAC OS

Tags: xampp

instale xampp , todo iba bien hasta que decidi ponerle password desde php admin a mysql , se supone que el procedimiento era agregar password desde php admin y despues modificar el archivo de config.inc.php y ahi agregarle nuevamente el pass y guardar, pero al momento de guardar no me deja debido a que muestra un mensaje que dice que no tengo los permisos para modificar ese archivo, despues lo intente modificar desde la terminal pero tampoco pude , despues intente cambiarle los permisos para lectura y modificacion desde finder y terminal con chmod 777 pero tampoco tuve exito , alguien podria decir como se configura conrrectamente el password de phpmyadmin, acontinuacion dejo unas imagenes de en que paso me quede.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema no deja aplicar los cambios con chmod ya viste alguna alternativa??

Comment: No funciona, Jorge, porque precisamente me pide tener permisos para realizar esa acción (eliminar el archivo o sustituirlo por el modificado).

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente únicamente permite abrirlo en sólo lectura. La solución que encontré fue copiar el archivo config.inc.php en alguna otra carpeta externa a xamppfiles/phpmyadmin y realizar las modificaciones al password. Una vez copiado y modificado este archivo, puedes eliminar el original (no deberías tener problemas en este paso) y reemplazarlo por el que modificaste. Si recargas la página localhost/phpmyadmin, ahora sí te dejará acceder correctamente.

Comment: Aún así no me deja modificar archivos, hice lo que sugieres pero cuando intentaba remplazar el archivo no me fue posible, porque no tengo permisos para realizar modificaciones en dicha carpeta. También probé editando con "nano" el archivo config.inc.php desde la consola con super administrador y tampoco tenía permisos. ¿Alguna solución?